# would have been saving vs would have saved

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions, continuous

On a website (Quora.com) I read the following question and answer:

> Did the US President Clinton really stop Pakistan from nuking India in
>   1999 and save india?
>
> Answer:
>
> If they had, they *would have been saving* Pakistan, not India.

Why he did not say they *would have saved* Pakistan ?

What is the difference ?

Thank you.

Comment: "If they had" is not specific enough. *nuking* or *stopped from nuking*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you will find the nuance expressed by the progressive here addressed at [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13331/32): where the simple construction asserts the **fact** of the action, the progressive ascribes a character or **quality** to it.

This use is typically found in contrastive situations like that in your example, where the speaker/writer is concerned to draw a distinction between two interpretations of an event or action:

> He wasn’t serious, he was just joking. *(not "he just joked")*

The contrast often addresses a distinction of motive, and it may be that your writer is saying that President Clinton's *intention* was to save Pakistan rather than India; but I think it more likely that the writer means that if Pakistan **had** nuked India India would have responded with such ferocity that Pakistan would have been destroyed.